# Unable to view LTTNG profile from ARM on Eclipse Trace

Tags: lttng

I have successfully cross compiled **LTTng** for arm and been able to do a quick test on the board. I performed **LTTng sessions** on a build machine and on the board. Was able to interpret both sessions using Babeltrace. That's fine. But on **importing to Eclipse**, only the session from the build machine was displayable. What gives? Is it not outputting in the same formats?

**Few more information:** under both session directories, there are `channel.idx` and metadata files. But only for the build session, Eclipse shows it as one icon, with CPU usage, LTTng Kernel Analysis, Tmf Statistics Analysis. For the board, it just lists the files.

Has any one met the same problem? Or were able to interpret an **LTTng embedded session** on Eclipse?

Comment: I've managed to partially resolve the problem mentioned above. Now loadable by Eclipse but data turned out mostly garbage such as -IRQ numbers and non-terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse plugin (recently renamed to "Trace Compass") uses its own implementation of a Java CTF reader, it's quite possible for it to have discrepancies with Babeltrace. It also hasn't been tested a lot with ARM traces, so it can definitely be a bug in the parser.

If you could open a bug on the [bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tracecompass), and attach the problematic trace, it would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Dear Alex, advice taken. Bug reported on bug tracker. Thanks for your help.